# Jumbotron help responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

can you help make this jumbotron bg image responsive? i've read several topics but none was able to work. thanks!
Here's the HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Practice Website 1 Bootstrap</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigational Start Container-->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
            <a href class="navbar-brand">E-DATA TECHNOLOGY</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


            <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"> <!-- Dropdown Link Start-->
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MEDIA<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                <li><a href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TWITTER</a></li>
                </ul> <!-- Dropdown Link End-->
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div> <!-- Navigational Start Container-->

        <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Success!!!</h1>
<p>Removed Jumbotron Padding and Margin/ still not a success
</p>
        </div> 


    <div class="container"> <!-- Grid System Content -->
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3><a href="#">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR 1</a></h3>
        <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit 
    lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit 
    lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit 
    lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit<a class="btn btn-danger">ReadMore</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3><a href="#">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR 2</a></h3>
        <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit 
    lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit <a class="btn btn-danger">ReadMore</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3><a href="#">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR 3</a></h3>
        <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit 
    lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.  <a class="btn btn-danger">Read More</a></p>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <!-- Footer Start-->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
        <p class="navbar-text pull-left ">KREATIV TECH COPYRIGHT 2014</p>
        <a href="http:youtube.com"class= "navbar-button btn-danger btn pull-right">Subscribe on Youtube</a>
    </div> <!-- Footer Start-->

        <!-- jquery and javascript start script -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> <!-- JS End Script-->
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my Custom CSS

```
    body {
padding-top: 51px;
padding-bottom:70px;    
}

.jumbotron{
    background: url(http://wowslider.com/images/demo/pinboard-fly/data/images/dock.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
.jumbotron{
    background: url(http://wowslider.com/images/demo/pinboard-fly/data/images/dock.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
}
```

I'm unable to make it responsive everytime i add a padding-bottom:200px because the image won't show actual height.

Comment: What text are you trying to have displayed over the image? Or does the jumbotron solely only contain the image?

Comment: Maybe this would work? http://jsfiddle.net/1vdfLcyt/2/

Comment: If you add a background image to a div, jumbotron or otherwise, the height of the div, if not set by CSS, is what's inside the div, plus padding.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hewun/1/ -- you have to play around with it and also background-size: cover and basically any of the background-size stuff is not compatible with IE8, so you have to create fall backs.

Comment: the bg image inside the jumbotron and a little text. if i add padding, it messes up the image being responsive on smaller screens.

Comment: Hi Christina, can you please show me your css? it seems to be working with what you coded.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hewun/1/edit

Comment: thanks! added 2 media queries and somehow it work. only problem is if going below the specified width size the image messes up. how can i lock the site resize to a specific width? for example up to 320px?

Comment: max-width media query and then make adjustments.

Comment: The image actually doesn't mess up, it's acting normal. Your logo text is too long. You need to adjust the space or the top padding of the site at that size.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hewun/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Simple ! Use `background-size:100%;`

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/KnMSSVcvdy)

```
.jumbotron {
            background: url(http://wowslider.com/images/demo/pinboard-fly/data/images/dock.jpg) no-repeat center center;
            -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
            -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
            -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
            background-size:100%;
        }
```

Hope this may useful !

Comment: ok i tried this, but what happens is it pushes down the image, the text and background area shows outside the jumbotron i just noticed it doesn't display the whole image but only a part of it.

Comment: No its correct only, Its inside the area of jumbotron

Comment: at fullscreen i add a padding-bottom:100px; and it shows just the way i want it. is it possible to set a rule using media queries so that when i scale the view size it would remove the padding style?

Comment: Hi jake, actual image size is big. is it necessary that i adjust it to fit the actual jumbotron width and height?

Comment: Ok ok i understood ! Vergara

Comment: i actually tried media queries, doesn't seem to be working with what i have. can you show me the way? ",

Comment: thanks for all the help! was able to fix it using 2 media queries.